# Should I use Oauth2 for facebook login authentification with Xamarin.Forms or should i use Facebook SDK?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

Using xamarin.forms I have an issue with login authentication through Facebook.  Im using Oauth2 and I am interested to see if this is the way to go. Or should I use Facebook SDK native login.

I got it to working fine through Google. And I am not certain if facebook even allows app to be published with Oauth2 code for login through facebook.

Here is my authenticator, constants don't matter they all work fine. What matters is the last bool.

```cs
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId,
    scope,
    new Uri(Constants.FacebookAuthUrl),
new Uri(Constants.FacebookRedirectUrl),
null, false);
```

The false  is for IsUsingNativeUI.

I would like to use the native ui, but if i set it to true I will receive back success with a red warning from facebook.

SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anynone...

And the page won't return to my application. With false it does work, but you have to manualy enter your username and password each time.

Does anyone have any experience with login in through facebook? Could you point me in correct direction?
I would appreciate your assistance. Thank you either way. :smiley:

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FacebookClientPlugin ?

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Being hasty, I went and connected through the facebook native sdk. But it seems to me that this is a usefull plugin you wrote there. I don't quite see where it allows you to natively login (to login through facebook app already installed on the phone). But it might be there.


 For now I am going to use Facebook SDK, if some kind of a big problem occurs I will be sure to visit your solution.